# How can i add a random redirect button in wordpress?

Tags: plugins, buttons

I need a random redirect button just like 9gag.com. I know that i need a add a rewrite rule but i dont know how to do this

I tried to use plugins and other codes, but none worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this code

```
add_action('init','random_add_rewrite');
function random_add_rewrite() {
   global $wp;
   $wp->add_query_var('random');
   add_rewrite_rule('random/?$', 'index.php?random=1', 'top');
 }

 add_action('template_redirect','random_template');
 function random_template() {
   if (get_query_var('random') == 1) {
           $posts = get_posts('post_type=post&orderby=rand&numberposts=1');
           foreach($posts as $post) {
                   $link = get_permalink($post);
           }
           wp_redirect($link,307);
           exit;
    }
 }
```

ANd then use this for random redirect

```
 <a href="http://.....com/?random=1/" >Random Post</a>
```

Comment: it looks like half of that code is not relevant to the answer